# Criar um foreach com uma condição especifica no PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Tenho essa condição:

`if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d'))`

E tenho também um array. Para cada entrada do array preciso verificar a condição e mostrar na tela os dados da posição, e se não, preciso mostrar algo com o mesmo espaço só que com os itens vazios... Como eu poderia fazer um foreach com um condicional como esse?

o que tenho até agora é isso:

```
while ($arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())){
   if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
      echo 'Nome:'. $arrayBancas['nome'];
   }                       
}
   if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) != $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
      echo 'Nome:----------VAZIO--------------';
   }                       
}
```

Desse jeito funciona perfeitamente para uma única entrada da condicional verdadeira do primeiro if, mas se duas ou mais entradas executarem ele, o outro não executa pela segunda ou mais vezes, e eu preciso que isso aconteça...

Comment: O primeiro `if` é quando tem dados da banca, e o segundo quando não tem, certo? Todos os registros devem estar em um estado ou outro? Não entendi porque agora está falando em `foreach`.

Comment: @Alceu E onde está o _array_ que você disse que tem? Pelo código da pergunta estou vendo que vc tem linhas de uma base de dados. Você quer um monte de campos vazios quando for dia diferente, e um monte de campos preenchidos quando for a data corrente?

Comment: E alterei a outra pergunta, talvez seja o que você quer. Esta pergunta fala de coisas que não estão presentes no código, tá difícil entender. Se é outra coisa, precisa explicar melhor.

Comment: Isso! Preciso de vários campos vazios quando o dia for diferente. Para cada registro eu preciso de vários outros vazios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma função nativa do PHP chamada Array_map, ela aplica uma função definida (no caso a sua validação) para cada elemento do array, veja o [manual dela aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php).

Você pode criar algo do tipo:

```
function checkCondition($pos)
{
  if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d'))
  {
    return $pos;
  }
  else
  {
   return '';
  }
}
```

E então você usa o array mapa mais ou menos assim:

```
$novo_array = array_map("checkCondition",$seuArrayAtual);
```

Se você der um *print_r* na variável `$novo_array` você verá que as posições para as quais a verificação é verdadeira estão preenchidas, caso contrário elas são nulas.

Comment: Você conseguiu entender a pergunta? Explica pra mim :)

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, ele precisa fazer uma verificação a cada posição que ele ler no array, caso a verificação seja verdadeira então o array retorna o valor do próprio array, caso contrário ela seria nula.

Comment: Eu entendi outra coisa completamente diferente ao ponto de achar que esta resposta não chega nem perto do que ele quer.

Comment: É que ele diz: "E tenho também um array. Para cada entrada do array preciso verificar a condição e mostrar na tela os dados da posição, e se não, preciso mostrar algo com o mesmo espaço só que com os itens vazios". Ele precisa fazer a verificação para cada item do array.

Comment: Exatamente isso! É isso que eu preciso, enquanto percorro as posições do $arrayBancas eu preciso testar o que tem dentro e fazer uma coisa outra para todas as vezes que o percorrimento acontecer.... Vou tentar dar uma simplificada ali no código... A propósito, tô tentando aplicar esse array_map aqui e não tô conseguindo... Eu teria que adicionar os dois if dentro da função? Não está dando certo...

Comment: No caso, o while está percorrendo o $arrayBancas, que traz vários campos e várias entradas do MySQL e, para cada uma dessas entradas, preciso de campos vazios para onde o dia for diferente

Comment: Você pode substituir o else pelo outro if. Lembre-se que a função fica separada, ela não tem nada a ver com a linha do array_map